# How can I toggle between json files in javascript without page reload

Tags: javascript, json, switch-statement, toggle

I am playing around a hangman game (found on the web) using json file as a quizbank processed by js controller. There is only one file with quiz-words (quizbank.json) connected to the controller. I want to add some options like level, topic etc. by putting each option into separate json file and connecting them to the controller. Suppose, I have some files (quizbank1.json, quizbank2.json etc.) What is the best way to switch between them, preferably on the same page i.e. without reloading html.  Below is the entire code. The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var questionBank=new Array;
    var wordArray=new Array;
    var previousGuesses=new Array;
    var currentWord;
    var currentClue;
    var wrongAnswerCount;

        $.getJSON('quizbank.json', function(data) { 
        for(i=0;i<data.wordlist.length;i++){ 
            questionBank[i]=new Array;
            questionBank[i][0]=data.wordlist[i].word;
            questionBank[i][1]=data.wordlist[i].clue;
        }
        titleScreen();
        })//gtjson


function titleScreen(){
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="gameTitle">HANGMAN</div><div id="startButton" class="button">BEGIN</div>');      
    $('#startButton').on("click",function (){gameScreen()});
}//display game
function titleScreen(){
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="gameTitle">HANGMAN1</div><div id="startButton" class="button">BEGIN1</div>');        
    $('#startButton').on("click",function (){gameScreen()});
}//display game
function titleScreen(){
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="gameTitle">HANGMAN2</div><div id="startButton" class="button">BEGIN2</div>');        
    $('#startButton').on("click",function (){gameScreen()});
}//display game
function gameScreen(){
    $('#gameContent').empty();
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="pixHolder"><img id="hangman" src="man.png"></div>');
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="wordHolder"></div>');
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="clueHolder"></div>');
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="guesses">Previous guesses:</div>');
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="feedback"></div>');
    $('#gameContent').append('<form><input type="text" id="dummy" ></form>');           
    getWord();
    var numberOfTiles=currentWord.length;
    wrongAnswerCount=0;
    previousGuesses=[];

    for(i=0;i<numberOfTiles;i++){
        $('#wordHolder').append('<div class="tile" id=t'+i+'></div>');
    }

    $('#clueHolder').append("HINT: "+currentClue);

    $(document).on("keyup",handleKeyUp);
    $(document).on("click",function(){$('#dummy').focus();});
    $('#dummy').focus();
}//gamescreen

function getWord(){
    var rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*questionBank.length);
    currentWord=questionBank[rnd][0];
    currentClue=questionBank[rnd][1];
    questionBank.splice(rnd,1); 
    wordArray=currentWord.split("");            
}//getword          
function handleKeyUp(event) {

    //this line deals with glitch in recent versions of android
    if(event.keyCode==229){event.keyCode=$('#dummy').val().slice($('#dummy').val().length-1,$('#dummy').val().length).toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);}

    if(event.keyCode>64 && event.keyCode<91){
        var found=false;
        var previouslyEntered=false;
        var input=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

    for(i=0;i<previousGuesses.length;i++){if(input==previousGuesses[i]){previouslyEntered=true;}}

        if(!previouslyEntered){
            previousGuesses.push(input);
            for(i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++){
                if(input==wordArray[i]){found=true;$('#t'+i).append(input);}    
            }//for

            if(found){checkAnswer();}
            else{wrongAnswer(input);}
        }//if
    }//if
}//handlekeyup

function checkAnswer(){
    var currentAnswer="";   
    for(i=0;i<currentWord.length;i++){
        currentAnswer+=($('#t'+i).text());
    }       
    if(currentAnswer==currentWord){
        victoryMessage();
    };
}//checkanswer

function wrongAnswer(a){
    wrongAnswerCount++;
    var pos=(wrongAnswerCount*-75) +"px"
    $('#guesses').append("  "+a);
    $('#hangman').css("left",pos);
    if(wrongAnswerCount==6){
        defeatMessage();}
}//wronganswer

function victoryMessage(){
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $(document).off("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    $('#feedback').append("CORRECT!<br><br><div id='replay' class='button'>CONTINUE</div>");
    $('#replay').on("click",function (){
        if(questionBank.length>0){
            gameScreen()}
        else{finalPage()}
    });
}//victory

function defeatMessage(){
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $(document).off("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    $('#feedback').append("You've Lost!<br>(answer= "+ currentWord +")<div id='replay' class='button'>CONTINUE</div>");
    $('#replay').on("click",function (){
        if(questionBank.length>0){
            gameScreen()}
        else{finalPage()}
    });
}//defeat
function finalPage(){
    $('#gameContent').empty();
    $('#gameContent').append('<div id="finalMessage">You have finished all the words in the game!</div>');
}//finalpage

    });//doc ready
```

The json:

```
{"wordlist":[
    {
        "word":"kangaroo",
        "clue":"an animal"
    },

    {
        "word":"starbucks",
        "clue":"a company"
    },
    {
        "word":"macaroni",
        "clue":"a kind of food"
    }   
]
}
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Hangman Game</title>
    <link href="main.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">Hangman Game</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="gameContent">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  background-color:#ECD69D;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
#topbar{
 height:50px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:50px;
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:36px;
 width:800px;
 border-bottom:solid white 1px;
}
#gameContent{
 margin:auto;   
 width:800px;
 height:600px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color:#A98F4C;
 border-radius:15px;
}
.spacer{
    height:30px;
}
#gameTitle{
 margin-top:100px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:40px;
 color:#fff;
}
.button{font-size:17px;
 width:100px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:solid 1px white;
 border-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
}

.button:hover{
 background-color:#6AB0FD;
}

#replay{
 margin-left:0px;}
#wordHolder{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:150px;
}

#clueHolder{
 margin-top:130px;
 margin-left:150px;
}

#guesses{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:150px;
}

#pixHolder{
 margin-left:30px;
 width:75px;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#pixHolder img{
 position:relative
}

#feedback{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:150px;
 font-size:34px;
 color:#fff;
}

.tile{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
 background-color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:24px;
 color:#333;
 padding-top:5px;
}

#finalMessage{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:40px;
 color:#fff;
 width:90%;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:100px;
}

#dummy{
 position:absolute;
 left:-200px;
 top:0px;
}
```

Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: you've provided very little to work with ... can you show some HTML and at least some attempt to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, thanks for your reply. I added all parts of the code. This is working prototype. I just want to add some json files containing different levels and topics.

Comment: Still need help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, someone repeatedly abused me on stack, so I told a joke, and got binned for the joke!!!